# How to replace out of index error without using try or except python 3.0?

Tags: python

Ive been working on a sample program and I was wondering whether we could check if an index exists or not after a certain index for ex: index[2] (out of index bound error would show up if no value is in that index). I wanted to know if we could check without using try or except method and if index is not there print out error.

I want to show the error and add it to a list later on

for eg:
l = [1,2,3]

> > > 1[5]
> > >       out of bound error
> > >       instead i want it to be 
> > >       "error: add more detail" without any of the error in red popping up

Comment: Use `len()` on the list to see how long it is.

Comment: So why not just use `try...except`?

Comment: Because im working on something that we are not allowed to use try or except

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer with OP's comments:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

index = 10

if len(array) < index:
    print "Index not in array"
```

Index is set to 10 in this example as a demonstration, but in your program you would use wherever you are getting your out of bounds index value.

Comment: I want to add an error if the second index is not there

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of an array with the len() function.

```
arr = [1,10]
len(arr)
>>> 2
```

Comment: if in a method I want it to say error before and index error pops out

Comment: I would like to add an error if second index not there before the actual error pops up

Answer (score 0):

the happy mamba's answer:

> array = [1,2,3,4]
>
> index = 10
>
> if len(array) < index:
>          print "Index not in array"

covers almost all cases, however if

```
index = 4
```

then

```
len(array) == index
```

and no error is produced, so you would run into your old friend the IndexError, so it would be better to use

```
if len(array) <= index:
    print("Some error text")
```